# CursorLoader - Two tables join query?

Tags: android, join, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I am having two tables with 1:1 relationship, I am using content provider and cursorloader.

**How would I make a join query to work with cursor loader?** I could hack it up somehow with rawSql inside content provider but how to do it in cursor loader constructor is beyond me.

Thanks a lot !

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ARTICLES = "create table "
            + TABLE_ARTICLES + "("
            + COLUMN_ARTICLE_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_URL + " text not null unique, "
            + COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_PRICE + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_ADDED + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_IMG_URL + " text);";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ARTICLE_DETAIL = "create table "
            + TABLE_ARTICLE_DETAILS + "("
            + COLUMN_ARTICLE_DETAIL_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_DESC + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_LOCALITY + " text, "
            + COLUMN_TYPE + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_SELLER + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_SELLER_PHONE + " text, "
            + COLUMN_IMAGE_COUNT + " integer default 0, "
            + COLUMN_ARTICLE + " integer, foreign key (" + COLUMN_ARTICLE + ") references " + TABLE_ARTICLES + "(" + COLUMN_ARTICLE_ID + "));";
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to need to write raw SQL to do joins.

Comment: how would I write a raw SQL query when creating Cursor Loader? It only accepts those strings as parameters (projection, selection, etc)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to use a custom task loader. 
In a nutshell, one solution is to create a Uri "content://AUTHORITY/TableArticlesWithDetail". 
Then in your content provider, check for that Uri and do a raw SQL to do the join.

See [how to use join query in CursorLoader when its constructor does not support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090695/how-to-use-join-query-in-cursorloader-when-its-constructor-does-not-support-it) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution is to create a view that joins your tables and access the view from your CursorLoader using a Uri.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = db.query(
    RefuelTable.TABLE_NAME + " , " + ExpenseTable.TABLE_NAME,
    Utils.concat(RefuelTable.PROJECTION, ExpenseTable.PROJECTION),
     RefuelTable.EXP_ID + " = " + ExpenseTable.ID + " AND  "  +    RuelTable.ID + " = " +  id ,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null);
```

**Do like This**