# how to use join query in CursorLoader when its constructor does not support it

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having two tables with 1:n relationship, I am using content provider and cursorloader.

How would I make a join query to work with cursor loader? I could hack it up somehow with rawSql inside content provider but how to do it in cursor loader constructor is beyond me.

Thanks a lot !

**CursorLoader(Context context, Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)**

How will query for join when Uri could only point to one table

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `Uri` does not point to any table. It points to whatever you feel like pointing it to.

Let's pretend that your two tables are `Customer` and `Order`. One customer may have many orders. You want to execute a query to get all outstanding orders... but you want to join in some customer-related columns that you will need, such as the customer's name.

Let's further pretend that you already have `content://your.authority.goes.here/customer` and `content://your.authority.goes.here/order` defined to purely query those tables.

You have two choices:

1. Add the join of the customer's display name on your `/order` `Uri`. Having another available column probably will not break any existing consumers of the provider (though testing is always a good idea). This is what `ContactsContract` does -- it joins in some base columns, like the contact's name, on pretty much all queries of all tables.
2. Create `content://your.authority.goes.here/orderWithCust` that does the same basic query as `/order` does, but contains your join. In this case, you could have `insert()`, `update()`, and `delete()` throw some sort of `RuntimeException`, to remind you that you should not be modifying data using `/orderWithCust` as a `Uri`.

In the end, designing a `ContentProvider` `Uri` system is similar to designing a REST Web service's URL system. In both cases, the join has to be done on the provider/server side, and so you may need to break the one-table-to-one-URL baseline to offer up some useful joins.

Comment: I read your answer above but in my case whole point of using join is to retrieve columns from multiple related table with just one query. inside a single cursor that i get from cursor loader i need DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY from ContactsContract.Contact table ,ACCOUNT_NAME from ContactsContract.RawContact table and DATA1 from ContactsContract.DATA table.Now i dont understand how single Uri can help me with this because if i give Uri pointing to ContactsContract.RawContact table then how will i access related columns of ContactsContract.Contact and ContactsContract.Data table

Comment: @AbhishekChauhan: Well, in your case, you did not write the `ContentProvider`, which means that you cannot "hack it up somehow with rawSql inside content provider", as you claimed in your question. My answer is aimed at somebody who is writing the `ContentProvider` and therefore can do the join inside of it. In your case, you will have to manually "join" your data yourself from multiple `Cursor` objects, and the `Loader` framework will not help much in this area. Off the cuff, I'd use an `AsyncTask`, then do queries using `ContentResolver` and merge your data in `doInBackground()`, I guess.

Comment: ya ... thanks i will use asynctask for it and merge later...this one will suit me better

Comment: @CommonsWare: can you explain option one in some more detail with an example. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution using sub-classes of ContentProvider.
Let's say you have table tblA and another table tblB. I recommend creating two classes "AContentProvider" and "BContentProvider". Most importantly, make sure that both tables are set up in the same database.

The main part of the solution is to override ContentProvider.query() in the ContentProvider that you will call from your CursorLoader - the URI decides which one it is:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sort) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    qb.setTables(
            "tblA LEFT JOIN tblB"
                    + " ON ("
                    + "tblA.b_id"
                    + " = "
                    + "tblB.id"
                    + ")"
    );

    ...
    // Content of projection is set by CursorLoader
    // usually in an Activity that implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<>

    Cursor c = qb.query(
            database,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            groupBy,
            having,
            orderBy
    );

    ...
    return c;
}
```

As you can see, the **JOIN is done in setTables()**. Using **projection** you make sure that you only display the columns you really need and most of all, you have no duplicate columns, like "id" from both tables:

```
final String[] projection = new String[] {
        "tblA.*",
        "tblB.columnThatOnlyBHas"
};
```

Make use of the override and try to get as much work done in the sub-classes as you can; for example: all my overridden query() methods call setNotificationUri() to notify the ContentResolver if the cursor result set changes.:

```
c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
```