# Join Two tables and get the cursor for Cursorloader

Tags: android, sql

I am trying to join two tables and get a cursor from it so that i contains results from both the table
and i can pass that cursor in CursorAdapter.

I tired to Google the solution, got many but not able to implement it right

I tried this solution but do not able to figure out what it means. 
[how to use join query in CursorLoader when its constructor does not support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090695/how-to-use-join-query-in-cursorloader-when-its-constructor-does-not-support-it)

My tables are like this .

Table - Deal (Id, name, sms, title,categoryid,subcategoryid)

Table - SubCategory (Id, name, status,title,categoryid)

I want to join my these two tables such that "Get all deals where subcategoryid.status=true"

Answer (score 0):

what are the keys in both tables? also, is the subcategory in the Deal table the same as Id column in the SubCategory table?

Comment: are you using oracle?

Comment: First i am using sqllite , in android

Comment: Second = the keys are subcategoryid in deals table and id in subcategory table.

Answer (score 0):

select  d.id, d.name, d.sms, d.title, d.categoryid, d.subcategoryid, sc.name, sc.title, sc.categoryid
from Deal d, SubCategory sc
where  d.subcategoryid = sc.Id and sc.status = true;