# Sort a CursorLoader using column present in another table

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have:

- **Three tables:** `products`, `orders` and `order lines`.
- **A CursorLoader and a CursorAdapter:** `ProductsOrderLoader` and `ProductsOrderAdapter`.
- **ListView:** a simple `products` listview.

For the time being, my list view shows `products` bought in a certain `order` (`order lines`), plus the rest of the `products`.

But these items are sorted by `productName`. What I want is to sort these products by `quantity`, however the `quantity` column belongs to another table `orderLine`.

Is it possible to stick to using `CursorLoader` and achieve the sorting of `listview` using a column present in another table?

Comment: Use join as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090695/how-to-use-join-query-in-cursorloader-when-its-constructor-does-not-support-it

Comment: Thanks @eduyayo that's exactly what I'm searching for, but I need a code to copy from it? I can't find out how a `column` from `tableB` is added to `tableA`'s `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Well, a content provider is just kind of the interface but within the implementation, instead of just queriying one single table you have to sql join both. There's no hidden secret to that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here: [Get all the products, and putting a specific order's product first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956901/get-all-the-products-and-putting-a-specific-orders-product-first/26956914#26956914) using only `orderBy`, without having to modify the `ContentProvider`.