# Get all the products, and putting a specific order's product first

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables: **products**, **orders** and **orderLines**(order_id, product_id).

I have an sql query to figure out which seems nearly impossible to do in `only one query`.
Is there a way to have in only one query:

- All the products but showning a specific order's products first;
  which means that: for an `order A`: show `product1`, `product2`.. present in `orderA's orderLines` first, than the `following products` (not ordered) are shown next.

**PS:**
I know it's possible to achieve this with a `union` of two queries, but it would be better to have it done in `only one query`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a subquery in the `order by` clause.  In this case, an `exists` subquery is what you need:

```
select p.*
from products p
order by (exists (select 1
                  from orderlines ol
                  where p.productid = ol.productid and o.orderid = ORDERA
                 )
         ) desc;
```