# Join query of default content:// tables within CursorLoader

Tags: android, mysql, join, android-cursorloader

This may be a very specific question so I'm asking here.
Also, I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090695/how-to-use-join-query-in-cursorloader-when-its-constructor-does-not-support-it) but this does not apply in my case.

Shortly, I'm trying to join two `content://` tables and then I should pass the result to a `CursorLoader`.

I've tried to write a rough selection clause as

```
Uri frequent_contact = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_STREQUENT_URI;
Uri all_contacts = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
String selection = "'" + frequent_contact + "._id' = '" + all_contacts + "._id'";
```

or

```
String selection = frequent_contact + "._id = " + all_contacts + "._id";
```

Because the _id value is an int but it is saved as a String.

Then I return `new CursorLoader(context, all_contacts, null, selection, null, null);`

In the first case the app runs but the adapter is not filled, in the second case the app crash.

So, is it possible to join two `content://` table? And if yes, how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, it is not possible... ContentProvider is a different abstraction level ... do not think about CP as a database(well, mostly it is implemented with sqlite but can be any implementation - fx direct REST api) ... but there is a CursorJoiner in android api

Comment: @Selvin thank you, I'll have a look at that CursorJoiner.